# How to use Newtonsoft.Json as default in Asp.net Core Web Api?

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, json.net

I am new to **ASP.Net Web Api Core**. I have been using **ASP.Net MVC** for past few years and I always have written an `ActionFilter` and used `JSON.Net` for `Serializing` data into `JSON`. So, in that way I replaced Microsoft's `JavaScript Serializer` (which is slower than `JSON.Net`) with `JSON.Net` (it is claimed to be 400% faster).

How to do all this in **ASP.Net Web Api Core**? Where to change the **default formattor**?

Note: Please feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In .NET Core 3.0+ include the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` and then replace

```cs
services.AddControllers();
```

in `ConfigureServices` with

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

This is a pre-release NuGet package in .NET Core 3.0 but a full release package in .NET Core 3.1.

I came across this myself, but I've found that the same answer with some additional info is in [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55666826/).

**Edit:** As a useful update: code with the call to `AddNewtonsoftJson()` will compile and run even without installing the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` NuGet package. If you do that, it runs with *both* converters installed, but defaulting to the `System.Text.Json` converter which you presumably don't want since you're reading this answer. So you *must remember to install the NuGet package* for this to work properly (*and* remember to re-install it if you ever clear down and redo your NuGet dependencies).

Comment: this saved my lot of time, and i was able to migrate to .net 3.1. seamlessly

Comment: This saves me! Thanks. I upgraded my application from 2.2 to 6. There are lots of cases that uses dynamics object. So instead of resolving them on every case, I tried this solution and it works like a charm. Thank you.

services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

Comment: I did same, but this is breaking my JsonConvert.DeserializeObject.
Below is what I did after getting response from controller:
var res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var validationResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myModelName>(res);

Its breaking at the desterilize line. If I use services.AddControllers(); only, post will work, but patch wont.

Answer (score 34):

ASP.NET Core already uses JSON.NET as `JavaScriptSerializer` isn't implemented/ported to .NET Core.

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` depends on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Formatter.Json` which depends on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch`, which depends on `Newtonsoft.Json` (see [source](https://github.com/aspnet/JsonPatch/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch/project.json#L29)).

#### Update

This is only true for ASP.NET Core 1.0 to 2.2. ASP.NET Core 3.0 removes the dependency on JSON.NET and uses it's own JSON serializer.

Comment: Hi Tseng. Thanks for taking time and helping. I have commented out the newtonsoft's dependency in project.json but web api is still working, how is that?

Comment: It told you already. You are referencing one (likely `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc´) and it references Formatter.Json and it has dependency on JsonPatch and JsonPatch finally brings in Newtonsoft.Json. You can't "comment out" the JSON.NET dependency unless you remove all Mvc related packages, but then you got a console application

Comment: So basically, even if I remove the reference, it still loads it because JSON.Net is a dependency for JsonPatch? Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @SuperCoder: Exactly. It will however load the version which is referenced by MVC (9.0.1 as of ASP.NET Core MVC 1.1). If you want a newer version (i.e. Json.NET 9.0.2-beta2 for example), then you need to add the reference yourself to your application csproj/project.json

Comment: Great info... I discovered the version used by the .Net Core MVC is `Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.1`

Comment: Great answer. I just Write JsonConvert and resolve the namespace and it's automatically showing the Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Author of Newtonsoft.Json JamesNK works at Microsoft dotnet team since end of March 2018. https://twitter.com/jamesnk/status/978719138347495424. Guess what stands behind the Json serializer in .NET Core 3.0? I liked this.

Comment: @Demir: One of the reasons for `System.Text.Json` is to remove the dependency of ASP.NET Core on JSON.NET (since it was quite hard to use a newer version of JSON.NET with ASP.NET Core since its build on a specific version, i.e. as time of writing of the answer 9.0.1). The other is performance and that the author doesn't want breaking changes (new Span Api would require that) and its would be a major rewrite of the hole library

Answer (score 6):

here is a code snippet to adjust the settings for a .net core application

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => {
            // send back a ISO date
            var settings = options.SerializerSettings;
            settings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
            // dont mess with case of properties
            var resolver = options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver as DefaultContractResolver;
            resolver.NamingStrategy = null;
        });
}
```

Comment: This code is for setting the default configurations of the Newtonsoft.json not for changing the serializer.

Comment: so this works, but i need special cases, i.e. sometime i might just need yyyy-MM-dd.  I've got a custom attribute for this, `[JsonConverter(typeof(DateOnlyConverter))]` that works with regular newtonsoft, how do i make `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` recognize my custom attribute?