# Serialize AsyncCallback

Tags: rest, callback, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm converting a project that uses WCF to WebApi. AsyncCallback objects can easily be passed on as if it's a normal method call. However, when trying to deserialize the result in my .NET Core WebApi, it produces errors.

```
public class AsyncRequest {
[JsonConstructor]
public AsyncRequest () {}
public AsyncCallback Callback { get; set; }
}

// The object is being used in methods like this:
[HttpPost]
[Route("action")]
public IActionResult Action ([FromBody]AsyncRequest request) {
}
```

I have several other WebApi methods working, including with objects to send information. So it's not an issue with WebApi in general.

Comment: What's the error you got? You could try to [adding `NewtonsoftJson`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59649201/13655939) in `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: @MichaelWang Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'method'), looking at the JSON it does have such a paramter, but with property name "method0", so it looks like they have different serialization/deserialization methods.

Comment: @MichaelWang When I replace that in the JSON with "method" it produces the error "member 'value' was not found".

Comment: Hi, @MrFox, without the Json and the completed object, I can't see the error. I suggest you check the json you post via JSON formatter & Validator and deserialize object properties which is same from JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

These callbacks are how async methods are implemented in WCF.
Since we're now using WebApi all calls are async by default.
So this implementation is no longer needed.