# Marking a property as Json Required with Newtonsoft just makes object null

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a request object for my API and I want to enforce that my properties are always present in the body. Here is my object:

```
public class Code
{
    [JsonProperty("id", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I don't pass in the `type` property in my request body, my `Code` object is null. Instead I would want a bad request error to get propagated back to the client. Will the Newtonsoft decorator not do that for me here? Or would I have to manually add checks to see if the properties are not null?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: [...as it's working](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lhsNqg) ... prolly you are not using json.net (as new asp .net core is no longer using json.net but System.Text,Json) but it's just blind guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following code throws for me as expected:

```cs
string serialized = @"{ 'noId': '123' }";  
Code deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Code>(serialized);
Console.WriteLine(deserialized.Id);
```

My code class:

```cs
    class Code
    {
        [JsonProperty("id", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Can you confirm Newtonsoft.Json is used? If you are using ASP.NET Core 3.x or above, please refer to [How to use Newtonsoft.Json as default in Asp.net Core Web Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290811/how-to-use-newtonsoft-json-as-default-in-asp-net-core-web-api) to set your project up to use `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: yep looks to be an issue with the fact that Newtonsoft isn't used as the default serializer

Answer (score 1):

[Fluent Validation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) is the solution for you. So, you don't have to use `JsonProperty` attributes.

**Usage:**

First, create a validator for your class.

```
public class CodelValidator : AbstractValidator<Code>
{
    public CodelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.id).NotEmpty().WithMessage("id is required.");
        RuleFor(x => x.type).NotEmpty().WithMessage("type is required.");
    }
}
```

Inside your controller method:

```
public ActionResult TestMethod(Code code)
{
    var validator = new CodeValidator();
    var validationResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(code);
    if (validationResult.IsValid == false)
    {
        var errorMessages = validationResult.Errors.Select(s => s.ErrorMessage);
        // manage how you want to show the erros.
    }
    ...
}
```

So, as you get all the errors. Now you can show however you want.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1064

Currently the value for JsonProperty.Required only determines if the value is required - it does not allow you to indicate that a value may or may not be null.

Also in looking at the code it looks like all empty strings get converted to null

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L282