# How to set default JSON Serializer in MAUI?

Tags: json.net, maui, system.text.json, maui-blazor

Microsoft.Text.Json imposes some restrictions that are not configurable - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-8-0#some-limits-not-configurable.

Because of this limitation I cannot share large data to BlazorWebView as parameter to a function in JS using `InvokeVoidAsync`.

So, I want to set Newtonsoft.Json as default serializer for my MAUI app. How can this be achieved in Hybrid MAUI app?

I tried finding APIs similar to ASP.NET - [How to use Newtonsoft.Json as default in Asp.net Core Web Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290811/how-to-use-newtonsoft-json-as-default-in-asp-net-core-web-api) to configure default serializer, but could not find it.

Comment: This is due to the limitation of `System.Text.Json`. `System.Text.Json` sets limits that can't be changed for some values, such as the maximum token size in characters (166 MB) and in base 64 (125 MB).  See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39953

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Thanks. I get that. This is the reason I am trying to change the default json serializer.

Comment: How about use the command: global using Newtonsoft.Json; Is it enough?

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas using global using directive would still not change the serializer used in Microsoft implementation if I am not mistaken.

Comment: By using global all calls for json will use by default the newtonsoft.json. Where do you want to change the serializer?

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas I want to change the serializer user by WebView i.e. internal Microsoft code.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change it, btw, I notice that you've opened a discussion on Github:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/20260, you can also follow up there.